# How to share link from web to Messenger on mobile

Tags: share, messenger

In my application I have a button responsible for sharing a specific link to Messenger. While on mobile web, I would like it to open new Messenger message with prepopulated link and no addresee on both Android and iOS.

It seems, like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web was a great solution, but as it is mentioned in the link, they stopped supporting it.

Is there any other way to achieve what I am looking for?